# pyspark jobs failed with " OperationalError:(SQLDriverConnect) "

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, database-connection, sqlconnection, dbconnection

I am running multiple pyspark jobs in parallel and for few of them I am getting error like this:

> OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Please help me here.

Comment: Have you tested ODBC driver connection, whether it is successful or not?

Comment: yes ,for most of pyspark jobs its working as expected, I think there is a problem with multiple concurrent connections.